# PHPmailer is sending copy to my email

Tags: php, smtp, copy, phpmailer

When I'm sending a test message via PHPmailer (SMTP) my email appends to the recepients list. Here is what recipient sees in inbox email

> To: mail@mail.com, Name <mail2@mail.com>

The second email is mine. How can I stop this?

Here is my code

```
function send_email($to, $fromName, $subject, $message, $contentType='text', $smtp_opts) {
    $mail = new PHPmailer();
    $mail->SetFrom($smtp_opts['fromEmail'], $fromName);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->IsHTML($contentType=='html');

    $mail->Host = $smtp_opts['host'];
    $mail->SMTPAuth = (bool)$smtp_opts['auth'];
    if ($mail->SMTPAuth) {
        $mail->Username = $smtp_opts['username'];
        $mail->Password = $smtp_opts['password'];
    }

    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AddAddress($smtp_opts['fromEmail'], $fromName);

    $result = $mail->Send();

    $mail->ClearAddresses();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();
    return $result;
}

$smtp_opts = array( ... ); // host, port, fromEmail, auth, username, password
send_email('mail@mail.com', 'Name', 'Subj', 'Msg', 'html', $smtp_opts);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mail->AddAddress($smtp_opts['fromEmail'], $fromName);
```

If I am not mistaken, this command adds another recipient to the list of recipients. Try to remove it and send another test E-Mail. You shouldn't be getting the copy-mail then.

Comment: Oh my god!... I was sitting since morning looking for this mistake... Holy sh_t!:(

Comment: @NikitaGavrilov Don't sweat it, I know EXACTLY how you feel. Sometimes it just takes one glance from another person to spot the problem, the programmer has spent hours on looking for. Though it'd be nice if you accepted one of the answers :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line 
    $mail->AddAddress($smtp_opts['fromEmail'], $fromName);